# NPM start error: events.js:160 throw er; // unhandled 'error' event

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache

I still have this error.. and hasn't found out the way to solve, can anyone help of me this? I read questions in here but none of them actually helped me out..

```
$ npm start

> daehan@1.0.0 start C:\Users\DaeHan
> budo index.js --live

[0003] info  Server running at http://1.224.129.91:9966/ (connect)
[0003] info  LiveReload running on 35729
[0003] 16ms        256B GET    200 / (generated)
[0003] 378ms      1440B (browserify)
[0004] 0ms        1440B GET    200 /index.js (generated)
events.js:160
       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
       ^

Error: watch AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files EPERM
 at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1443:19)
at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1470:11)
 at createFsWatchInstance (C:\Users\DaeHan\node_modules\chokidar\lib\nodefs-handler.js:37:15)


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! daehan@1.0.0 start: `budo index.js --live`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

It worked like 5 seconds on localhost:9966 and immediately it turned out to "site can't be reached" page.. I tried delete all caches and refreshed npm, temporary internet files and tried to change localhost path on Apache httpd.congf (listen 9966, ServerName localhost:9966).

It seems I need to do something specifically for this.. and I saw one solvable answer was

> What you have to do is to add the above in the User Variables > PATH > add "C:\Windows\System32\"

but as much as I'm new, I have no certain idea how to do this.. can anyone please help of this..?